# Can't find where the time is consumed

Tags: c#

I have one function which gets the list of files present in a FTP folder.

Function:

```
    public static List<string> GetFileList(NetworkCredential credential, string FTPSite, string FTPFolder, string extension)
    {
        string LSOutput = "";
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        bool isSuccess = false;
        int retrier = 1;

        while (isSuccess == false && retrier <= MaxRetries)
        {
            try
            {
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("--Attempt " + retrier + ":", LogMessageType.Simple);

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + FTPSite + FTPFolder);
                request.Timeout = 120000;
                request.Credentials = credential;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.EnableSsl = true;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                FtpWebResponse response = null;
                response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                LSOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();

                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("--Succeeded", LogMessageType.Simple);
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("--Failed. Details: " + ex.Message, LogMessageType.Error);
            }

            retrier++;
        }

        if (!isSuccess)
            throw new Exception("All attempts failed");
        else
        {
            //Parse the LS
            string[] LSOutputLines = LSOutput.Trim().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string LSOutputLine in LSOutputLines)
                files.Add(LSOutputLine);

            //Filter files
            files = files.Where(f => f.ToLower().EndsWith(extension.ToLower())).ToList();

            PrepareLogAndEmail("Total " + extension.ToLower() + " files found: " + files.Count, LogMessageType.Simple);
            return files;
        }
    }
```

Below is how it is called:

```
        //-------------------------------------------------------//
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("Step 1: FIND FILES ON THE FTP FOLDER", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.StepStart);
            filesOnFolder = CommonHelper.GetFileList(credential, FTPSite, FTPFolder, ".pgp");

            if (filesOnFolder.Count == 0)
            {
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("Atleast one file was expected but not found", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.Simple);
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("Step 1: COMPLETED", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.StepComplete);
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("(Took " + (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds to complete)", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.TimeTaken);
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail(HeaderMessage, CommonHelper.LogMessageType.Header);

                CommonHelper.SendMail(CommonHelper.EmailSubjectType.Informative);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("Step 1: COMPLETED", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.StepComplete);
                CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("(Took " + (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds to complete)", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.TimeTaken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("An exception occured. Details: " + ex.Message, CommonHelper.LogMessageType.Error);
            CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("Step 1: COMPLETED WITH ERRORS", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.StepComplete);
            CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail("(Took " + (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds + " seconds to complete)", CommonHelper.LogMessageType.TimeTaken);
            CommonHelper.PrepareLogAndEmail(HeaderMessage, CommonHelper.LogMessageType.Header);

            CommonHelper.SendMail(CommonHelper.EmailSubjectType.Bad);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------//
```

In some cases I get output as:

```
Step 1: FIND FILES ON THE FTP FOLDER
--Attempt 1:
--Succeeded
Total .pgp files found: 2
Step 1: COMPLETED
(Took 4.2742904 seconds to complete)
```

One of the output is like this:

```
Step 1: FIND FILES ON THE FTP FOLDER
--Attempt 1:
--Failed. Details: The operation has timed out
--Attempt 2:
--Succeeded
Total .pgp files found: 0
Atleast one file was expected but not found
Step 1: COMPLETED
(Took 370.6597195 seconds to complete)
```

First attempt: 120 seconds
Second attempt(worst case): 119 seconds
Total: 239 seconds

Extra time (370-239): 131 seconds

I am not sure where this 131 seconds are spent.
PrepareLogAndEmail= Function which logs strings to a text file.
MaxRetries = 3

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ use it to find out :) it'll locate time consuming methods

Comment: use profiler in vstudio

Comment: I would not prefer to use Environment.Exit() , also how are you doing the tests? running debug/release executables?

Comment: Using `DateTime` to benchmark performance is a very bad idea with only  ~100 ticks p/second how can you expect any sort of reliable accuracy? Use the `Stopwatch` class, it was built for this purpose. You can query the `Stopwatch.Frequency` property to see how much more accurate it is (~4million ticks p/sec on my machine)

Comment: Also, you state `Can't find where the time is consumed`. If you look at the output from your second example, it's clear that the request is timing out, so find out __why__ and then you'll have your answer.

Comment: @DGibbs I am not concerned with accuracy of milliseconds. In my case it's 131 seconds.

Comment: @7-isnotbad I am deplying it in production where there is no visual studio. Just exe is running there.

Comment: @AkshayJ Completely irrelevant. `Stopwatch` was __designed for this purpose__. It's also much easier to use. Why are you using the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: @DGibbs what you are saying is that using a wrong tool can cause error of 131 seconds ?

Comment: @AkshayJ No. Using the wrong tool in this instance can result in a vastly inaccurate benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to record your timings.

I see that there is the following after the `catch` statement in `GetFileList`:

```
Console.WriteLine("First retry (GetFileList)");
Console.ReadKey();
retrier++;
```

The timer will continue to run while waiting for user input. Is it possible the first attempt failed and it took you 131 seconds to press a key in the command window?

Comment: I removed those two lines. Actually those lines I posted for some other testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch** instead **DateTime**;

```
// Create new stopwatch
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();

// Result
var elapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```